# Extreme slow server response due to 400,000 coupons generated with woocommerce coupon generator plugin and slow MySQL Server overload and response

Tags: mysql, database, performance, woocommerce, overloading

I decided to try out Coupon Generator for WooCommerce plugin and found out its great. Only did I know this would cause a huge setback for our website performance.
Our site is operating on 2 DEDICATED SERVERS with 16 CPU CORES each for the webserver and DATABASE server. We got to observe that since creating over 400,000 COUPONS with Coupon Generator for WooCommerce plugin (which was a mistake I ddnt know of and was ignorant because I thought it wouldnt cause any setback for slow response on the site), the site became ultimately and extremely slow. It takes about 40 to 60 seconds to respond. The load time is great which is under 1 second.

On checking, the DATABASE SERVER. we got the following results:

root@mysql ~]# top -H

top – 12:34:47 up 6 days, 11:05, 2 users, load average: 32.71, 34.69, 39.46
Tasks: 528 total, 43 running, 485 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
Cpu(s): 86.1%us, 12.3%sy, 0.0%ni, 0.0%id, 0.0%wa, 0.0%hi, 1.5%si, 0.0%st
Mem: 10120336k total, 7859684k used, 2260652k free, 182484k buffers
Swap: 4095996k total, 0k used, 4095996k free, 6448320k cached

PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+ COMMAND
35108 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 19.9 7.1 0:01.74 mysqld
35104 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 19.3 7.1 0:01.71 mysqld
35117 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 19.3 7.1 0:00.79 mysqld
35111 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 18.9 7.1 0:01.65 mysqld
35080 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 18.6 7.1 0:02.25 mysqld
35065 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 18.3 7.1 0:01.68 mysqld
35134 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 18.3 7.1 0:00.73 mysqld
35053 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 18.0 7.1 0:04.17 mysqld
35121 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 18.0 7.1 0:01.79 mysqld
35133 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 18.0 7.1 0:00.76 mysqld
35126 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 17.6 7.1 0:00.71 mysqld
35127 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m S 17.6 7.1 0:01.07 mysqld
35136 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 17.6 7.1 0:00.65 mysqld
35141 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 17.6 7.1 0:00.76 mysqld
35094 mysql 20 0 1898m 703m 12m R 17.3 7.1 0:01.71 mysqld

This is extremely overloaded. The site calls the MYSQL TABLE OF over 80MB which is extremely heavy.

I would like to ask because, how can we reduce the 400,000 COUPONS generated with you plugin to 20,000 because its affecting us and we are paying heavily monthly to main the site due to this. In addition to this, the site is extremely load to respond.

Please anyone help!

Comment: so you want to delete 380K and keep only 20K regardless if the coupon is used before or not?

Comment: I would like to delete this and inturn, make sure it doesnt affect users who have already used some of the coupons because there is no way I can ascertain which of the coupons has been relatively used on my platform. I would have love a way I can reduce the coupons size and at the same time, it would be active for my users and they would not be affected by this development. I am totally frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to delete coupon using built in function you can use `wp_delete_post( $id );`   as WooCommerce Store the coupon as custom post type.

so the following function will run and delete 100 coupon at time everytime the admin area is initialized and you can increase the limit if you want

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'count_coupon' );

function count_coupon() {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    global $wpdb;
    $copuns = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon' LIMIT 100" );
    foreach ( $copuns as $copun ) {

        wp_delete_post( $copun->ID );

    }
}
```

you can delete those coupon form the mysql directly but i prefer this way.

Comment: Thanks for your great response. But I have a question. Where do I paste the above code in my WooCommerce store files?

Comment: you are welcome :) you can post in   functions.php which you can find in your active theme directory

Comment: I am sorry for the many question. Once this code is paste in functions.php - It starts deleting coupons code anytime the wp-admin is called. Does the deletion happens randomly by 100, or it starts from the first 100 coupons in the table or the last 100 on the table. I am asking this question because my website gives out COUPONS from the top of the table. I am sorry if i bother you so much.

Comment: @BritishBIT-BankCryptocurrency this function will keep running till all coupons are deleted you need to remove this code once you are done it's deleted randomly 100 coupon  and it's not going to effect the discount which was applied before

Comment: Thanks so much. I just pasted the code. I have noted down the value of the coupons already on the database to confirm if they are being deleted. The wp-admin area takes about 2 mins to load a page. Its extremely SLOW.

Comment: What i mean is a more faster way to delete all coupons at once on the database. As of writing this comment. The time taken from write the comment above, my wp-admin is still loading and not opened yet.

Comment: @BritishBIT-BankCryptocurrency  it's normal to dashboard will be slow as this function is working in the background and each refresh it's delete 100 you can increase the limit to 1000 but you need to make sure your site will not break

Comment: you can delete them from the database directly but i wrote it using PHP just for safety as if you deleting those from DB you might do one simple mistake which might cause u more pain